# CakePHP select option attributes

Tags: php, cakephp, select, cakephp-bake

I'm new with CakePHP and I tried to do an admin panel.

In my dropdown list I can't show the 'label' instead of the id. I tried so many things...

My database is like :

**etats**

- id
- label

**projets**

- (many rows)
- etat_id

I tried to do this :

**Controller :**

```php
$etats = $this->Projets->Etats->find('all');
```

**View :**

```php
echo $this->Form->input('etat_id', ['options' => $etats]);
```

**Output :**

```html
<select name="etat_id" id="etat-id">
  <option value="0">
    {"id": 1, "label": "En cours"}
  </option>
</select>
```

Now, if i try to do this :

**Controller :**

```php
$etats = $this->Projets->Etats->find('list', array('fields' => array('Etats.id', 'Etats.label')));
```

*(same view)*

**The output is :**

```html
<select name="etat_id" id="etat-id">
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
</select>
```

It doesn't want to take the 'label' in my DB... I don't know what to do.

Thank you in advance and sorry again for this poor english :'(

Comment: Do you want to see the label before your drop down list ? Or don't want to see ? 
"it doesn't want to take the 'label' in my DB... I don't know what to do." it's not clear.

Comment: plz let me know what type of output you want. plz

Comment: what cakephp version?

Comment: I'm using CakePhp 3.2.6. I would like to have : <option value="ID">LABEL</option>. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it!

```php
$etats = $this->Projets->Etats->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'label']);
```

Will do :

```html
<option value="ID">LABEL</option>
```